# C# MYSQL connection using --login-path config?

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlconnection

In my local system, I have configured more than one instance in `.mylogin.cnf` mentioned below

```
shell> mysql_config_editor print --all
[instance_13001]
user = root
password = *****
host = localhost
port = 13001

[instance_21001]
user = mysqlappuser
password = *****
host = 166.25.48.133
port = 3306

[instance_26001]
user = mysqlappuser
password = *****
host = 205.41.48.133
port = 3306
```

and My c# code is

```
string InstanceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceName"];
string DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
    
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("--login-path "+InstanceName+";Databasename="+DatabaseName+";"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Dogs1", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

In my setting file have only database name and instance. Is there a possible way to achieve this?
Because I need to configure same exe with different Database in simple way.

Comment: In case of mySQL you should use `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand ` and `SqlDataReader `

Comment: @fubo thanks, I have searched for that and I get an idea from the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html. How can I change the connection string if I use the MysqlConnection? Could you please help for the same.

Comment: sure, your connection string has to look kile this https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: @fubo Sorry I can't see connection string with --login-path method. Actually my problem is I have already more than  300 configured processes(Export) are running by using --login-path method, now I need to create a new process(Import) with same --login-path because if we change the password in MYSQL server so we need to change the new password in 300 processes. That's why I tried to use same --login-path method

Comment: Otherwise, I need to keep common file for all database configuration but it might not be secure.

Comment: how about string manipulation? I've never heared about that `--login-path` scheme in connection strings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217741/discussion-between-prasanna-kumar-j-and-fubo).